# Can one find good distance-2-separators in planar graphs?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, planar-graphs

It is known that [planar graphs admit "good" separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_separator_theorem), allowing to design PTASes for specific problems such as MINIMUM INDEPENDENT SET by recursive separation of the graph.

However, it seems that this specific approach does not lead to a PTAS for the MINIMUM DOMINATING SET problem (MDS), whereas other approaches do, see [E. D. Demaine and M. Hajiaghayi: Approximation Schemes for Planar Graph Problems (1983, 1984; Baker)](https://erikdemaine.org/papers/PlanarApprox_Encyclopedia2008/).

In [T. Nieberg and J. Hurink: A PTAS for the Minimum Dominating Set Problem in Unit Disk Graphs](https://doi.org/10.1007/11671411_23) (also accessible [here](https://research.utwente.nl/en/publications/a-ptas-for-the-minimum-dominating-set-problem-in-unit-disk-graphs-2)), the authors define the notion of 2-separated sets, that is, a collection of subsets of vertices of a graph such that two vertices from different sets are at distance at least two from each other.
If a graph admits such a set (with additional suitable properties), they prove that MDS admits a PTAS. This is the case for unit disk graphs for example.

This notion is really similar to the technique of recursive separators in planar graphs, except for the distance-2 requirement. So my question:

**Do good (in the sens of usual separators) "distance-2-separators" exist in planar graphs, and if yes, can we compute them efficiently?**